# How to show two records on each row p:dataScroller

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces in my jsf project. The `p:dataScroller` component lists one record to one row. And I want to split area two column and list two record each row. But I can not find any documentation this issue. [Component link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/basic.xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this from the component. There is no option to e.g. configure `columns="2"` or something on the datascroller. But when I looked at the generated html, I saw a simple

```
<ul class="ui-datascroller-list">
    <li class="ui-datascroller-item">...</li>
    <li class="ui-datascroller-item">...</li>
    <li class="ui-datascroller-item">...</li>
    <li class="ui-datascroller-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

structure being generated. So I started playing a little with the css (in the end, it is always html and css on the client side with the help of javascript)

And So I searched in stackoverflow on how to display an `<ul>` in two columns. There are several Q/A on this, including [HTML/CSS Making a list be in rows, 3 boxes per row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368028/html-css-making-a-list-be-in-rows-3-boxes-per-row). This does not fully work in this case, but it made me confident I could get it to work, and I did.

Adding:

```
.ui-datascroller .ui-datascroller-item {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to the online PrimeFaces showcase made it work.

[image]

Using 31% gives you 3 columns

[image]

And if you want it 'responsive' (2 or 3 or 4 or... columns depending on screen size), use

[Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)